# What skill/attribute combination is used for tracking?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, tracking

In WoD, what is the combination of attribute and skill that should be used to follow a trail (animal or human footprints)?

Would it involves survival? Animal ken?

The only reference to following a trail I found in the core rulebook was in Equipment section:

> Surveillance Equipment
>   [...]
>   Dice can be added to Stealth-based rolls to trail someone.

But description of stealth doesn't fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default answer is Wits + Investigation. That will find you tracks of all kinds and the clues to keep following them. However, in specific circumstances, another skill suited to the environment would be better: Survival in the woods, Streetwise in a network of alleys.

That version of "trail" above is better defined as "to follow someone without them noticing," so Stealth is the best choice there.

Answer (score 3):

For your question I would say your looking for Survival as a skill and Intelligence or Wits for attribute. Depending on your style, I would go with int.

I don't think Investigation fits for your situations (or any tracking related activity) because of this from NWod Core book page 59:

> Investigation is the art and science of solving mysteries, examining seemingly disparate evidence to find a connection, answering riddles and overcoming paradoxes. It not only allows your character to get into the head of a killer to grasp his motives or plans, it allows her to look beyond the mundane world to guess at answers to mysterious problems, or to have a “eureka” moment that offers insight into baffling circumstances. Your character might realize that all murder victims have the same digits jumbled in their phone numbers, she might interpret a dream that has striking similarities to events in the real world, or she could recognize why an intruder took the time to paint a room red. Certain individuals such as law-enforcement officers, forensic specialists, scientists and investigators are trained in the art of examination, while others simply develop the knack through years of practice...

Investigation is more getting into the mind set of someone.

Survival is more about actual tracking.

I would go for Int + Survival for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

For Chronicles of Darkness, this is resolved through the Clues system, but is still Wits + Streetwise/Survival, depending on terrain.  Use Investigation to get an idea of what direction the target is going, and have a bonus on the tracking roll.  Wits assumes the trail is hot; to pick up a lukewarm trail, where you're able to go back to an office and give the matter good thought, use Intelligence.

Surveillance Equipment helps with the Stealth roll needed to observe someone without getting caught.  While it doesn't necessarily help track the person, it does help to not spook a target.  Otherwise, you're going to need either foot chase rules (if you're lucky), or start from the beginning.